# From Kafka json message to Snowflake table

Tags: json, apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to implement a Snowflake Sink connector so that can i load messages coming to a Kafka topic directly to an appropriate Snowflake table. So far, I could only get to the point of loading the raw json into a table with two columns (RECORD_METADATA and RECORD_CONTENT). My goal would be to directly load the json messages into an appropriate table by flattening them. I have the structure of what the table should be, so I could create a table and directly load into that. But I need a way for the load process to flatten the messages.

I have been looking online and through the documentation, but haven't found a clear way to do this.
Is it possible or do I have to first load the raw json and then do transformations to get the table that I want?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell what you're asking, but there's a Flatten transform that you can use on any connector https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/flatten.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the raw JSON first then you can do transformations.

> Each Kafka message is passed to Snowflake in JSON format or Avro format. The Kafka connector stores that formatted information in a single column of type VARIANT. The data is not parsed, and the data is not split into multiple columns in the Snowflake table.

For more information you can read [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-overview.html#schema-of-tables-for-kafka-topics)